# How to rewrite absolute paths when using play as proxy server?

Tags: java, playframework

I am trying to use play (Java - 2.3) as proxy server to publicly expose content from an internal HTTP server.

So far I managed to get most of the content I want to show but unfortunately some of the stylesheets and scripts are referenced using absolute paths and, of course, the only I get is a 404.

Is there a workaround for this or I should ask the other devs to change the paths for these files?

My routes file looks like this:

```
GET     /proxy/*path                          controllers.gateway.TestProxy.index(path)
```

and I forward the content using this method:

```
public static Promise<Result> index(String path) {
    final Promise<Result> resultPromise = WS.url("http://10.1.0.10:18406/"+path).get().map(
            new Function<WSResponse, Result>() {
                public Result apply(WSResponse response) {
                    response().setContentType("text/html");
                    return ok(response.getBody());
                }
            }
    );
    return resultPromise;
}
```

EDIT:
I have some scripts and stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fs/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fs/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Since they resides mostly in the same assets folder ("/fs/") I could just map all the folders but this would require to update my play routes file every time a developer from the other team change something in the way the resources are organised/stored. It's not a nice solution IMHO, but I could live with that.

My biggest problem are the several jquery ajax calls that mostly request to urls like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/query",
  processData: false,
  data: xmlDocument
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/queryall",
  processData: false,
  data: xmlDocument
});
```

Any help would be a lot appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example of the absolute paths you'd like to rewrite?

Comment: Still not clear.. Should `/query` go to `http://10.1.0.10:18406/query` ? Are you asking what to do with routes that don't start with `/proxy` ? I'm confused as to what behavior you want it to have.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I decided to go for more practical solution:
I asked the other developers to change all the ajax queries and use all the same URI pattern.

In this way, I created few different routes on my routes file, depending on the type of resource/call I have to forward:

I have something like:

```
GET     /                                           controllers.gateway.TestProxy.index()
```

and

```
public static Promise<Result> index() {
    final Promise<Result> resultPromise = WS.url("http://10.1.0.10:18406/").get().map(
            new Function<WSResponse, Result>() {
                public Result apply(WSResponse response) {
                        response().setContentType("text/html");
                    return ok(response.getBody());
                }
            }
    );
    return resultPromise;
}
```

for the html pages and

```
GET     /$file<.*\.js$>                       controllers.gateway.TestProxy.js(file)
```

for the js files.
The controller is the same as the one above except for the response Content-Type that will be "text/javascript" of course.

Regarding the AJAX queries, they are now all under the same path and I follow exactly the same mechanism.

Thanks @m-z for your time.